# Combin several proxy_pass location paths in nginx

Tags: nginx

Hi I have several locations for `proxy_pass`, e.g.:

```
location /v1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/myapp/v1;
    # other stuff
}
location /v2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/myapp/v2;
    # other stuff
}
location /beta {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/myapp/beta;
    # other stuff
}
location / {
    root C:/MyApp/build/;
}
```

Is there a way to combine the top three location paths (v1, v2, beta) into one location config? As they are quite the same (same other stuff as well) except the end bits of the `proxy_pass`. Thank you.

Comment: You could probably move the "other stuff" into the `server` block so that the same statements are inherited by all of the `location` blocks.

Comment: @RichardSmith ah ok, thank you. But what about those locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "other stuff" can probably move into the outer block so that the three `location` blocks only need to contain a single `proxy_pass` statement.

But you can use a *regular expression* `location` to match any URI beginning with `/v1`, `/v2`, and `/beta`.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/(v1|v2|beta) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /myapp$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    # other stuff
}
```

Note that the evaluation order of regular expression location blocks is significant. This will not affect you if the only other location block in your `server` block is `location /`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
location ~ ^/(?<dest>v1|v2|beta) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/myapp/$dest;
    # other stuff
}
```

This might cause some side-effects depending on your other configuration in the `server` block.

Comment: Thank you. Does this support other suffix? Like /v1/api, or /v2/api?value=123

Comment: This is a preifx match, so it matches anything starting with `/v1` etc.